# Etsy Api v3 __SELF__

Tags: api, self, etsy

In Etsy Api V2 we can use `__SELF__` as shopID but in Api v3 that gives error (Expected int value for 'shop_id' (got string)).

Endpoint in v2 (successful):

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/__SELF__/receipts
```

Endpoint in v3 (error):

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/__SELF__/receipts
```

So, how can we use `__SELF__` method in v3?
If not how can we get id of permission granted shop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{
    "access_token": "12345678.O1zLuwveeKjpIqCQFfmR-PaMMpBmagH6DljRAkK9qt05OtRKiANJOyZlMx3WQ_o2FdComQGuoiAWy3dxyGI4Ke_76PR",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": "12345678.JNGIJtvLmwfDMhlYoOJl8aLR1BWottyHC6yhNcET-eC7RogSR5e1GTIXGrgrelWZalvh3YvvyLfKYYqvymd-u37Sjtx"
}
```

OAuth grant token (`access_token`) includes user id (`12345678` in the example above), which is the internal user_id of the Etsy.com user who grants the application access.

The V3 Open API requires the combined user id prefix and OAuth token as formatted in this parameter to authenticate requests.

This numeric OAuth user_id is only available from the authorization code grant flow.

So we can get userid from `access_token` and then get shops using that userid.

PHP code to get userid and setting curl url:

```
$user_id=explode(".", $access_token)[0];
$curlUrl = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/users/'.$user_id.'/shops';
```